# Make a page with a parameter same as a page without parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to make this page:

https://mediastreet.ie/media-jobs/role-65678

same as this page using htaccess:

https://mediastreet.ie/media-jobs/role

So basically /role-65678 is a parameter like role-{parameter}. So when on /role-65678 i have a script that fetches this (65678) and displays the job according to it.

Comment: Welcome. To ask On Topic question, please read [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than editing your htaccess file, I would just reccomend sticking with a good old get method.

Use https://mediastreet.ie/media-jobs/role?id=65678

Then in the index.php file in the directory "role", use the get functionality as shown below.
    
     `<?PHP
     $id = $_GET["id"];
     //Code to follow
    ?>`

Past experiance tells me this will save alot of htaccess headaches!

All the Best.